# Exporting Listview data into an email

Tags: c#, listview

i need some help extracting data from a listview with one sub into an email. Is this possible and what is the best way to do this

I tried the below but it gives me the message for each item and doesn't add it together so i tried moving the message but it then errors

```
StringBuilder sb;
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem listViewSubItem in lvi.SubItems)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("{0}\t", listViewSubItem.Text));
            }

            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        }
```

(instead of marking me down please could you help me)

thanks

Comment: It's very difficult to answer your question. You say you get errors, but you don't tell us what errors - how should we help you remove an error if we don't know the error?

Comment: I didn't say errors. i get the messages for each row individually. but i really want it all together so i can add it to a script for an email. So it works but i need everything together and i'm not sure how to change my script to get that

Comment: Declare a new `sb` before entering the `foreach` block: `var sb = new StringBuilder();` and move the `MessageBox.Show(..)` after the first/outer `foreach` block.

Comment: That worked, but now i get them in a line is there a way to get them to appear undearneath each other like a list. thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome and Yes. Use a `List<string>` instead of the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work is this correct List<string> sb;
            sb = new List<string>();
            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
            {
                //sb = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem listViewSubItem in lvi.SubItems)
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format("{0}\t", listViewSubItem.Text));
                }
                
                
            }

            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options. Please note that I didn't test the code but it should as least show the approach.

### Using string builder

Here you simply append to your message and show the result

```
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem listViewSubItem in lvi.SubItems)
        {
            sb.Append(listViewSubItem.Text);
            sb.Append("\t");
        }
        sp.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

### Use a list

Here we split the process and add some more sematic in the code

```
    var lines = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem listViewSubItem in lvi.SubItems)
        {
            lines.Add(string.Format("{0}\t", listViewSubItem.Text));
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

### Or with less boilerplate

Here we try to write the code in a more readable way. (depending on personal taste)

```
var lines = listView1.Items.Select(item => string.Join("\t", item.SubItems.Select(si => si.Text);
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

### Performance

StringBuilder should be the fastest. The other examples create a lot of string instances just to throw them away after creating the full message. This seems to be not relevant in your case, but if you would create thousands of mails in a loop, think twice.

Comment: What happens on the list, the sub item ends up on a new line is there a way to stop that

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You want one row for each listView1 item and all sub items should be separated by tab. Right? What code do you use, what's the exact output (example would help) and what do you want to look different?

Comment: i think your first example did what i wanted sorry